# What is the best way to sort xml elements by attribute values in c#/.net 3.5

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have a XML file with data like:

```
<Details>
  <TableDef>
    <Column Name="Calldate" HeaderName="Calldate" SourceColumnName="Calldate" IsHidden = "false" Position="4" />
    <Column Name="Issue" HeaderName="Issues" SourceColumnName="Issues" IsHidden = "false" Position="3" />
    <Column Name="ParamortizedValue" HeaderName="paramortizedvalue" SourceColumnName="Value" IsHidden = "false" Position="1" />
    <Column Name="PercentBondTotal" HeaderName="percentbondtotal" SourceColumnName="Percentage" IsHidden = "false" Position="2" />
  </TableDef>
</Details>
```

I was wondering what would be the best and efficient way to filter and sort the elements by an attribute so that I can use that sorted elements further in my code?

In above example, I want to filter by "IsHidden = false" and then sort the elements by "Position" attribute.

I have the following code that will read all the elements without any sort:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var nodeTableDefInfo = doc.XPathSelectElements("/Details");
var elements = nodeTableDefInfo.Elements("TableDef").Elements();
foreach (var e in elements)
{
  //want to work on the sorted elements
}
```

Guys, Thanks for all the solutions. before I could read your solution I came up with this:

```
var elements = nodeTableDefInfo.Elements("TableDef").Elements();
var sortedElements = (from element in elements 
                where element.Attribute("IsHidden").Value == "false" 
                orderby element.Attribute("Position").Value ascending 
                select element);
foreach (var e in sortedElements)
{
//work on the sorted elements
}
```

Now, after going through the solutions, I really liked the solution and explanation provided by `GFK`. I guess I need some handling for nulls. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some more LINQ!

```
var sortedElements =
    from element in elements
    let hiddenAttribute = element.Attribute("IsHidden")
    let positionAttribute = element.Attribute("Position")
    where hiddenAttribute != null
        && positionAttribute != null
        && hiddenAttribute.Value == "false"
   let position = int.Parse(positionAttribute)
   orderby position
   select element;

foreach (var e in sortedElements)
{
    // ...
}
```

Edit: also, what I do usually with LINQ-to-XML is create an anonymous type so I can parse once and for all the attributes into strongly typed values (and handle missing or invalid values), like:

```
int parsedInt;
var sortedElements =
    from element in elements
    let hiddenAttribute = element.Attribute("IsHidden")
    let positionAttribute = element.Attribute("Position")
    // add other attributes here
    select new
        {
            IsHidden = hiddenAttribute == null || hiddenAttribute.Value != "false",
            Position = positionAttribute == null || !int.TryParse(positionAttribute.Value, out parsedInt)
                ? default(int?)
                : parsedInt,
            // add other parsed attributes here
        };
```

This way, all operations is made easier, like sorting or filtering:

```
foreach(var element in sortedElements.Where(e => !e.IsHidden).OrderBy(e => e.Position)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If you bind the anonymously typed object in a let statement you could also filter on it which you've emitted from your 2nd example.

Comment: True, it depends if you want to discard them definitely.

Comment: I liked the solutions and the explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var tableDefs = nodeTableDefInfo.Elements("TableDef").Elements();
foreach(var column in tableDefs.Where(x=>
                                 x.Attributes("IsHidden") != null && 
                                 bool.Parse(x.Attributes("IsHidden").value) == false && 
                                 x.Attributes("Position") != null)
                               .OrderBy(x=>int.Parse(x.Attributes("Position"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Linq2XML.

```
XDocument ip = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/data.xml"));
var op = ip.Descendants("Column")
    .Where(node => node.Attribute("IsHidden").Value == "false")
    .OrderBy(node => int.Parse(node.Attribute("Position").Value))
    .ToList();
```

Now, `op` will be `List<XElement>`. Use `for` or `foreach` to manipulate it.

Comment: this will throw an exception if a node is missing either the 'Position' or  'IsHidden' attribute, and it will order based on the string value of the Position attribute, and not the int value (i.e. 10 will come before 2)

Answer (score 1):

linq..

```
string str = @"
            <Details>
                <TableDef>
                    <Column Name='Calldate' HeaderName='Calldate' SourceColumnName='Calldate' IsHidden='false' Position='4' />
                    <Column Name='Issue' HeaderName='Issues' SourceColumnName='Issues' IsHidden='false' Position='3' />
                    <Column Name='ParamortizedValue' HeaderName='paramortizedvalue' SourceColumnName='Value' IsHidden = 'false' Position='1' />
                    <Column Name='PercentBondTotal' HeaderName='percentbondtotal' SourceColumnName='Percentage' IsHidden = 'false' Position='2' />
                </TableDef>
            </Details>";
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(str);
List<XElement> columns = (from t in xml.Descendants("TableDef").Descendants("Column") where (bool)t.Attribute("IsHidden") == false orderby (int)t.Attribute("Position") ascending select t).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample approach:

```
            var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, XElement>>();
            foreach(var element in elements)
            {
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,XElement>(
                    element.Attribute("someAttr").Value,
                    element));
            }
            var sorted = from entry in list
                         orderby entry.Value.Attribute("someAttr").Value
                         select entry;
            // just test:
            foreach (var entry in sorted)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("attribute value: {0} - element: {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value.ToString()));
            }
```

We're retrieving your chosen attribute values and treat it as an index.

We create a dictionary (a list of key-value pairs to be precise, as those values may not be unique) and then we just sort the list by the key.

I assume that this attribute will be present for every `XElement` - if that's not the case, you need to check for null of course.